# Visual Studio Code: Failed to launch external program dotnet

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, dnx

Visual Studio Code 1.0.0

Mac OS X 10.11.4

DNX is installed and I can run .NET Core application from terminal. Getting the following error when try to run .NET Core project.

Output window:

> Failed to launch external program dotnet .
>
> spawn dotnet ENOENT

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that your project is written with RC2. I don't think you can run RC2 applications from VS yet.

Comment: I have the same issue too and I can confirm that I am using RC1

Comment: Released 1.0 version. Same issue.

Comment: This was happening to me with .net core release 1.0 on a Mac. It was because dotnet had previously crashed and there was an open error dialog in the background that needed to be closed.

Comment: I had to close the current folder in VS Code and open the correct root folder. VS Code asked to add missing settings (in .vscode folder). Chose Yes and I was able to debug the file. My folder structure is C:\Source\MyProject. I had opened VS COde to C:\Source. Instead I had to open it to C:\Source\MyProject

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem today - it seems to be caused by my running zsh as my shell and launching VS code from the terminal. When I launch from bash or using spotlight everything works.

Apparently VS code has some hacky dependencies on bash - there is a discussion about this issue here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8434

Comment: exactly. did you found any solution to fix zsh ?